# UITableView vs. UIWebView

Tags: ios, ios5

I am creating a data heavy application that needs to display several pieces of data and allow rows of that data to be selected for a more detailed view.  The application is destined for an iPad (not an iPhone).

The data is best suited for a grid layout--there is multiple pieces of information and none is necessarily more important than the other data.  In other words, I'm struggling to come up with a logical way to display it within the default single column world of a UITableView.

Here's the question:  should I suck it up and teach myself what appears to be the difficult task of subclassing UITableView and trying to use multiple views to create multiple columns or, should I just use a UIWebView, create a traditional HTML table, and capture clicks of rows of the table as events to spawn a new view.  I presume the latter option is possible?

I've looked at some of the available open source grid classes--but, they all seem a bit limited either in ascetics or in functionality (i.e., being able to click on rows like a UITableView).

I'm starting to feel like I'm treating the iPad like a glorified web browser, but, the limited text formatting and table formatting options within iOS is feeling pretty limiting.  But.. it's hard to deny how easy HTML is to work with---and, for a casual programmer, I'm tempted by the lazy route.

I'd like to get people's sense on what would be the best (or acceptable) practice.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to subclass UITableView. Subclass UITableViewCell. Also, with respect to text and table formatting, it is really only limited by your ability (please don't be offended by that, we've all been there). You should force yourself to do these things with native code (webview only for displaying html) so that you learn how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I've done columns views using the standar tableview and custom Cells, each cell have as many buttons as columns I need, each button have the same target but different tag which is my way for differentiating them, then with this tag which is kind of my indexPath.row I can acces my data source (an array in my case) any way I want.

The other solution as you said is to rely on some grid-based view classes, there are plenty, [this is a quick search on cocoa controls](http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=grid%20view&commit=Search)

Comment: +1, except view tags are an abomination. You should have a cell subclass with outlets to the individual buttons. It's O(1) for lookup, doesn't lead to collisions, is safer with the typing system, and is just *cleaner*.

Comment: I use the tag for knowing wich button(Cell) have been pressed (in the action method for the button) as every button points to the same action, I can't think of any way of differentiating them other than [sender tag], I actually like this because it acts like the indexpath.row, any suggestion?

Comment: The cell has outlets to the buttons, and then you just do `if (sender == [self button1]) { ... } else if (sender == [self button2]) { ... }`. Or if you don't know how many buttons there'll be, put then in an Outlet Collection and use `[outletCollection indexOfObject:sender]` to figure out their "column".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your basic premise is that you need to display a grid of tappable information. The first thing I do when I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish something on iOS is to think about how Apple would do it.

In this case I would look at how Apple implemented the iPad App Store's scrolling grid. If you look at the raw data coming into the iPad via wireshark etc you can determine that Apple is actually just using a UIWebView and a ton of HTML/CSS3/webkit animations to make it look like it's native. This allows apple to create this very custom piece of UI and furthermore it allows them to update the entire UI on the fly.

Similarly, the iTunes Music Store on the Mac/PC is simply a specialized version of Safari/webkit that parses a massive XML document into UI.

Of course, you can always go with what you said and find a framework or custom subclass or even implement your own solution using custom `UIButton` objects and a `UIScrollView`.

Comment: I'm actually more keen on using a UIWebView given HTML is something I know--subclassing a UITableView or creating some custom UIButton seems like something I very much do not know.  If using a UIWebView isn't sacrilege, perhaps I'll go that route.

Comment: It's certainly Apple-approved. The most important thing to note is that you should strive to hide the fact that you're using a web view from your users. Spend a majority of your time tweaking the shadows on your font and adding subtle textures and noise etc using CSS3 and animate everything smoothly using webkit animations.